# Embedded tomcat rewrite rules not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, url-rewriting

I'm working in micro-services project and earlier all the services ran in standalone tomcat. It was working without any issues. Now we are migrating our app to AWS ECS using docker containers .

When application run in standalone tomcat , applying Rewrite rules to URLs working fine. But when I run same application in tomcat docker image, applying Rewrite rules to URLs not working.

Currently I'm working in activity-details-web service.
this is Java 8 project with some JSP templates .

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY target/activity-detail-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war details.war
COPY src/main/WEB-INF/rewrite.config /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config
EXPOSE 3010
CMD ["java", "-jar", "details.war"]
```

and this is my rewrite.config file

```
RewriteRule  ^/details/topactivitiesin([^/]+)/(.*)/js/(.*)$ /details/js/$3 [L,NE]
RewriteRule  ^/details/topactivitiesin([^/]+)/(.*)/images/(.*)$ /details/images/$3 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|css|js)
RewriteRule  ^/details/topactivitiesin([^/]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /details/$4 [L,NE]
```

and this is part of my properties file

```
server.port=3010
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.servlet.context-path=/details
base.url=http://localhost:3010/details/
```

this is how I run my docker image

> docker run -v E:/Projects/BackEnd/activity-details-web/src/main/WEB-INF/:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/  -p 3010:3010 docker.io/library/activity-details-web

and this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sium</groupId>
    <artifactId>activity-detail</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<relativePath/>-->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sium</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- hot swapping, enable live reload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>rewrite.config</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run

> http://localhost:3010/details/?activityCode=DX1048&source=2

this shows correct result. but when I try this,

> http://localhost:3010/details/topactivitiesinsri-lanka/Anuradhapura/Wilpattu_National_Park_/?activityCode=DX814&source=2

It's redirect to Error page(This page load when URL is incorrect)

P:S : When I run this application as spring-boot application using

> mvn spring-boot:run

here also rewrite rules not applying. **in my case rewrite rules applying only in standalone tomcat deployment**. How to fix this ?